# Deslizar item para incrementar TextView

Tags: android, listview

Existe algum componente que, ao deslizar um item de uma `ListView`, ele incrementa um `TextView` no próprio item?

Como na imagem abaixo:

Deslizando para a direita, incrementa de acordo com o valor que aparece o `TextView` da esquerda. O inverso acontece quando deslizamos para a direita.

[image: Imagem exemplo]

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se este tipo de pergunta é válida aqui no SO, uma vez que é sobre "pesquisa" de componente, e não dúvida de programação rs. Mas de qualquer maneira, segue resposta tirada do SO em inglês:

> [Este componente faz o que você precisa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437776/horizontal-slide-expandable-listview).

Exemplo de declaração na própia documentação do componente:

```
<com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView 
        xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/example_lv_list"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
        swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
        swipe:swipeActionLeft="[reveal | dismiss]"
        swipe:swipeActionRight="[reveal | dismiss]"
        swipe:swipeMode="[none | both | right | left]"
        swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="[true | false]"
        swipe:swipeOpenOnLongPress="[true | false]"
        swipe:swipeAnimationTime="[miliseconds]"
        swipe:swipeOffsetLeft="[dimension]"
        swipe:swipeOffsetRight="[dimension]"
/>
```

sendo que:

- swipeFrontView - **requerido** - view frontal
- swipeBackView - **requerido** - view de fundo

[Respota original no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437776/horizontal-slide-expandable-listview)

Comment: Já testei este componente e já tentei implementar minhas necessidades, mas não serviu. Na verdade o que preciso é conforme arrasto o item e conforme o número aparece o textview do item recebe o valor. No caso eu não clico em nenhum botão, apenas o deslizar do item define o valor. Talvez você tenha alguma ideia de como implementar neste exemplo que você enviou

Comment: Você quer por exemplo, um wheel spinner no backView ? ai conforme o valor selecionado, ele mando para o frontView ? Se não for isso, edite sua pergunta colocando imagens para deixar mais claro. Mesmo eu não sabendo como, pode aparecer outra pessoa que saiba como :)

Comment: Mas tem uma imagem do componente com o item sendo arrastado...

Comment: Pra mim pelo menos não está claro, não tem como você explicar melhor o que você precisa ? e por acaso, o item da backView que você está querendo dizer, seria um tipo de whell spiner ?

Comment: Não, nada haver. Vou explicar a imagem: Tem um listview, onde cada item tem um jogo. Repare que um dos itens foi deslizado para a direta (jogo da Espanha) e por baixo do item aparecem os números 0, 1, 2. No caso se o usuário desliza o item o suficiente para apenas aparecer o item 0 então o TextView correspondente a Espanha vai receber o valor 0. Caso deslize até o valor 2, então o TextBox correspondente da Espanha vai receber o valor 2. É isso que preciso. A imagem eu extrai do aplicativo Palpiteros que tem na play Store caso tenha interface de conhecer o listview que necessito.

Comment: Agora entendi. Eu não conheço nenhum componente que faça isso, e pelo que li nos fontes deste, ele também parece não fazer. Mas fiquei curioso para saber qual seria o comportamento do componente no caso de um palpite de 7x1 (tipo alemanha x brasil, corinthians x santos) rs.

Comment: No caso se você arrastar a lista até o fim aparece um popup para você digitar o valor.